# substr the date function in php from the full representation of the day of the week to the first letter

Tags: php

I'm uncertain on how to do it and it seems a bit tricky, is it possible?

```
date('l/m/d')
```

Using this date function it returns

Tuesday 4/30

I only want to return the first letter of the day of the week.

T 4/30

As usual any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I have to concat it into a sql query like so:

```
sum(case when DATEDIFF(dd,cast(GETDATE() as date),cast(a.follow_up as date))='1' then 1 else 0 end) 'W " . substr(date('l/m/d'), 0, 1) . strtotime('+1 day') . "',
```

update answer, i had to concat the second part of date again:

```
'" . substr(date('l/m/d', strtotime('+1 day')), 0, 1) . date('m/d') . "'
```

Comment: What happens with Thursday?

Comment: I don't need Saturday or Sunday, but Thursday would be necessary.

Comment: @HeadWay You don't get it. What they are meaning is: how would you know if T 4/30 is a Tuesday or a Thursday ?
By the way you can use something like this `echo date('l')[0] . date(' m/d');`

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV: That is >= ver 5.5 right?

Comment: @Raidenace no, it's **PHP 5.4+**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
echo substr(date('l'), 0, 1);
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/PHKI6S)

If you want the first two letters, which may be more useful, use:

```
echo substr(date('l'), 0, 2);
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/d7Xn9C)

Comment: Thank you, i was close but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: one more quick question, what if i'm using strtotime as well.. i'm throwing a syntax error for this:  substr(date('l/m/d'), 0, 1); strtotime('+1 day')

Comment: Try `substr(date('l/m/d', strtotime('+1 day')), 0, 1);`

Comment: That substr the date for l but than i lose the m/d, so i just get a capital W for wednesday and nothing else.

Comment: @HeadWay you can concatenate the `m/d` part... `. date(' m/d')`

Comment: still a bit confused on the entire syntax, i'm getting real close though. I'll post what i got.

Comment: '" . substr(date('l'), date(' m/d'), strtotime('+1 day'), 0, 1) . "',

Comment: I also tried this but i'm throwing a syntax error:  '" . substr(date('l') . date(' m/d'), strtotime('+1 day')), 0, 1) . "'

Comment: just looking for this last bit of help.

Answer (score 2):

```
// this will give you the first letter
echo date('l')[0] . date(' m/d');

// this is more effective... Deals with T for Tuesday/Thursday
// can easily be modified to take into account Saturday/Sunday
$day_part = date('l')[0] == 'T' ? substr(date('l'),0,2) : date('l')[0];
echo $day_part . date(' m/d');
```

Comment: I *think* this requires PHP 5.4 since array dereferencing wasn't offered until then, correct?

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV I was already working on the same solution :P But I did notice yours before posting this, so you can have the credit :)